# Is there a way to create pivot table with model table name using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot, pivot-table

I need to add an extra column using a custom formula which has to refer to the generated pivot table field value. So, I'm looking for a way to name the pivot table(Data model name) and then refer the generated value using that name.

I have tried to set value for name field of CTCacheField, but it doesn't create/name the model table name.

Here is the code that I have tried,

```
public void getScoreInPivotTable(String fieldName) {
    CTCacheFields ctCacheFields = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields();
    CTCacheField ctCacheField = ctCacheFields.addNewCacheField();
    ctCacheField.setName(fieldName);
    ctCacheField.setDatabaseField(false);
    ctCacheField.setFormula("'SUM(APPHNDL)'");
    ctCacheField.setNumFmtId(1);
    ctCacheFields.setCount(ctCacheFields.sizeOfCacheFieldArray());
}
```

I'm attaching screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

PS: I want to set model table name for the pivot table.

Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this? 
Please feel free to improve this question.

Comment: Create a file in Excel that does what you want, then unzip the `.xlsx` file and check the xml files to see what `CT` elements are needed to make it happen?

Comment: I tried doing it. "Range1" is associated with "x15:pivotTableUISettings" tag. So does that mean, it's not possible to do with Apache POI?

`<x15:pivotTableUISettings><x15:activeTabTopLevelEntity name="[Range1]"/></x15:pivotTableUISettings>`

Comment: `Range 1` is the name of a `Table` object in an `Excel` worksheet which is the data source of the pivot table. So what are you trying to achieve? Changing the data source of the pivot table?

Comment: I want to add one more column to the pivot table based on a custom formula. The custom formula refers to the already generated value in one of the columns in the pivot table and a column in the source table.
Example: To generate value for score column, the formula would look something like `AVERAGE(Range1[Column2])+0.4*[SourceColumn1]`
Here **Column2** is from pivot table and **SourceColumn1** is from source table

Comment: As it looks like your pivot data source is from an data connection. So if you are opening this in `Excel` how would you there "add one more column to the pivot table based on a custom formula"? What steps are necessary?